# How to get text from DialogBox without global variable usage

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there any way to get text from a dialog window created by `DialogBox` other than a global variable?

I mean, this is how I do it at the moment:

```
wchar_t str[80];
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
            if (GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT, str, sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str)) == 0)
                *str = 0;

            EndDialog(hDlg, wParam);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, wParam);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

But I wonder if it's possible to get rid of that `str` global variable?

Comment: A common method is to allocate a data structure that you store in the userdata of the window, which gives you "local" data within the window. But global variables aren't actually evil or anything so if it works for you just stick with it.

Comment: Consider CreateDialogParam(), gives you an extra pointer you can use for anything.  It can even point to a local variable since the function doesn't return until the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dialog box with `DialogBoxParam` which allows passing initialization data to the dialog.

In `WM_INITDIALOG`, use `SetWindowLongPtr` to save this data, then data is accessible in dialog procedure.

Note that with this method you are passing a pointer, therefore `sizeof(ptr)/sizeof(*ptr)` is not going to return the right allocation size.

Ideally, you may want to declare local variable `wchar_t *str = NULL;` and pass its address, then allow the dialog to allocate memory. The caller will then be responsible to free the memory.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, lparam);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wparam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        {
            wchar_t *str = (wchar_t*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
            if(str)
                GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, str, 80);
            EndDialog(hwnd, wparam);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        }
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    wchar_t str[80];
    if(IDOK == DialogBoxParam(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, 
        DialogProc, (LPARAM)(&str)))
        MessageBox(0, str, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, since `lParam` hasn't been used, can you set `lParam = (LPARAM )str` to save the address of str ?
Second, the return type is`INT_PTR`, but you only use to return TURE/FALSE, why not return the pointer value instead of `TRUE`(since the str pointer is always != NULL here):

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
            wchar_t* str = new wchar_t[80];
            if (!str)   return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
            if (GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT, str, 80) == 0)
                *str = 0;

            EndDialog(hDlg, wParam);
            return (INT_PTR)str;

        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, wParam);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Notes that, you'd better allocate memory for str in callback, so that the data won't be overwritten by others.
You of course could also use any IPC method, but it will get more complicated.