# Read access violation when setting value to object property, which was passed as LPARAM to callback function

Tags: c++, windows

I am building a small Windows app in order to learn C++ Windows programming. At the end of the question I am submitting full code for reference, so you can see everything in the context (I hope this approach is not exaggerated).
In my `WndProc` callback function, I parse `message` as follows:

```
case ID_SETUP_NUMBEROFFILES:
            callback_result = DialogBoxParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG3), hWnd, NumberInputDialogProc, (LPARAM)pState);
            if (callback_result) {
                OutputDebugString(L"ID_SETUP_NUMBEROFFILES (pState->N): ");
                OutputDebugString(pState->N.c_str());
                OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            DebugStateDisplay(hWnd);
            break;
```

`pState` is sent to dialog handling as `LPARAM` (see `pState` declaration and initialization in full code at the end). Dialog handler is:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK NumberInputDialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    StateInfo* pState = reinterpret_cast<StateInfo*>(lParam);
    switch (message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_NUMBER_EDIT, pState->N.c_str());
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDOK:
            TCHAR buffer[MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE + 1]; // +1 for null-terminator
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_NUMBER_EDIT, buffer, MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE + 1);
            OutputDebugString(L"buffer:");
            OutputDebugString(buffer);
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            // pState->N = buffer; // throws exception
            pState->N = std::wstring(buffer); // throws exception
            OutputDebugString(L"********* CALLBACK (pState->N): ");
            OutputDebugString(pState->N.c_str()); //throws exception
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            EndDialog(hDlg, IDOK);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, IDCANCEL);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

`pState->N` is correctly read in the case of `WM_INITDIALOG` message so at least I know that I am accessing right object. However both assignations to `pState->N` throw read access violation and what is puzzling me even more, even this:

```
OutputDebugString(pState->N.c_str()); //throws exception
```

throws exception, even though I am only reading it. I tried each one of the three in isolation (I commented out remaining two) so I can confirm that each throws exception.
What am I doing wrong? 
My goal was to read the value from dialog and assign it to `pState->N' or to rephrase:  I want to read from dialog, and set this value to application state. If this cannot be done directly, then indirectly is fine, if possible without any additional global variable.

Full code for reference:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include "resource.h"

#define VERSION _T("v0.2.0")
#define TITLE _T("MP3 Randomizer II")
#define DEFAULT_N  _T("900")
#define MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE 10

// Global variables
struct StateInfo {
    std::wstring inputFolder;
    std::wstring outputFolder;
    std::wstring N = DEFAULT_N;
    std::wstring selected = _T("0");
    std::wstring found = _T("0");
};

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("MP3 Randomizer");
static TCHAR szTitle[100];

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions :
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void PaintWindow(HWND hWnd, StateInfo* pState);
INT_PTR CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
INT_PTR CALLBACK NumberInputDialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
INT_PTR CALLBACK NotYetProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
std::wstring ShowFolderBrowserDialog(HWND hWnd);
inline StateInfo* GetAppState(HWND hwnd);
void DebugStateDisplay(HWND hWnd);

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {

    StateInfo* pState = new (std::nothrow) StateInfo;
    if (pState == NULL) return 0;

    _stprintf_s(szTitle, _T("%s %s"), TITLE, VERSION);

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"), _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"), NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    // Store instance handle in our global variable
    hInst = hInstance;

    // Load the menu resource
    HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));

    if (!hMenu) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to load menu resource!"), _T("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    // Extract the first (and only) menu from the loaded menu resource
    HMENU hSubMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);
    if (!hSubMenu) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to get sub-menu!"), _T("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,                                 // WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW : An optional extended window style.
        szWindowClass,                                          // szWindowClass: the name of the application
        szTitle,                                                // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,                                    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,                           // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
        800, 400,                                               // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
        NULL,                                                   // NULL: the parent of this window
        hMenu,                                                  // hMenu: the menu handle loaded from resources
        hInstance,                                              // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
        pState                                                  // pointer to state
    );

    if (!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"), _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"), NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
        // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
        // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    delete pState;

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    WORD wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    WORD wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    std::wstring selectedFolderPath;
    INT_PTR callback_result;
    int enteredNumber = 0;

    StateInfo* pState;
    if (message == WM_CREATE) {
        CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam);
        pState = reinterpret_cast<StateInfo*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pState);
    }
    else {
        pState = GetAppState(hWnd);
    }

    switch (message) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        PaintWindow(hWnd, pState);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (MessageBox(hWnd, L"Really quit?", TITLE, MB_OKCANCEL) == IDOK) {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wmId) {
        case ID_HELP_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, AboutDlgProc);
            break;
        case ID_SETUP_QUIT:
            if (MessageBox(hWnd, L"Really quit?", TITLE, MB_OKCANCEL) == IDOK) {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
            break;
        case ID_SETUP_INPUTFOLDER:
            selectedFolderPath = ShowFolderBrowserDialog(hWnd);
            pState->inputFolder = selectedFolderPath;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            DebugStateDisplay(hWnd);
            break;
        case ID_SETUP_OUTPUTFOLDER:
            selectedFolderPath = ShowFolderBrowserDialog(hWnd);
            pState->outputFolder = selectedFolderPath;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            DebugStateDisplay(hWnd);
            break;
        case ID_SETUP_NUMBEROFFILES:
            callback_result = DialogBoxParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG3), hWnd, NumberInputDialogProc, (LPARAM)pState);
            if (callback_result) {
                OutputDebugString(L"ID_SETUP_NUMBEROFFILES (pState->N): ");
                OutputDebugString(pState->N.c_str());
                OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            DebugStateDisplay(hWnd);
            break;
        case ID_ACTION_FINDMUSIC:
        case ID_ACTION_SAVELIST:
        case ID_ACTION_LOADLIST:
        case ID_ACTION_RANDOMIZE:
        case ID_ACTION_COPYTOOUTPUT:
        case ID_HELP_HELP:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2), hWnd, NotYetProc);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
void PaintWindow(HWND hWnd, StateInfo* pState) {
    int x1 = 5;
    int x2 = 120;
    int y = 5;
    int dy = 20;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR inputFolder[] = _T("Input folder: ");
    TCHAR outputFolder[] = _T("Output folder: ");
    TCHAR selected[] = _T("N Files to copy: ");
    TCHAR selectedNow[] = _T("Files selected: ");
    TCHAR found[] = _T("Files found: ");
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
    TextOut(hdc, x1, y, inputFolder, (int)_tcslen(inputFolder));
    TextOut(hdc, x2, y, pState->inputFolder.c_str(), static_cast<int>(pState->inputFolder.length()));
    y += dy;
    TextOut(hdc, x1, y, outputFolder, (int)_tcslen(outputFolder));
    TextOut(hdc, x2, y, pState->outputFolder.c_str(), static_cast<int>(pState->outputFolder.length()));
    y += dy;
    TextOut(hdc, x1, y, selected, (int)_tcslen(selected));
    TextOut(hdc, x2, y, pState->N.c_str(), static_cast<int>(pState->N.length()));
    y += dy;
    TextOut(hdc, x1, y, found, (int)_tcslen(found));
    TextOut(hdc, x2, y, pState->found.c_str(), static_cast<int>(pState->found.length()));
    y += dy;
    TextOut(hdc, x1, y, selectedNow, (int)_tcslen(selectedNow));
    TextOut(hdc, x2, y, pState->selected.c_str(), static_cast<int>(pState->selected.length()));
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}

// Dialog procedure for the About dialog box
INT_PTR CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        // Initialize dialog box controls and data here
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_STATIC2, VERSION);
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL) {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK NumberInputDialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    StateInfo* pState = reinterpret_cast<StateInfo*>(lParam);
    switch (message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_NUMBER_EDIT, pState->N.c_str());
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDOK:
            TCHAR buffer[MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE + 1]; // +1 for null-terminator
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_NUMBER_EDIT, buffer, MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE + 1);
            OutputDebugString(L"buffer:");
            OutputDebugString(buffer);
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            // pState->N = buffer; // throws exception
            pState->N = std::wstring(buffer); // throws exception
            OutputDebugString(L"********* CALLBACK (pState->N): ");
            OutputDebugString(pState->N.c_str()); //throws exception
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            EndDialog(hDlg, IDOK);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, IDCANCEL);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK NotYetProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        // Initialize dialog box controls and data here
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK) {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

std::wstring ShowFolderBrowserDialog(HWND hWnd) {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    std::wstring folderPath;

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        IFileDialog* pFileDialog;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFileDialog));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            // Set options for the folder browser dialog
            DWORD dwOptions;
            pFileDialog->GetOptions(&dwOptions);
            pFileDialog->SetOptions(dwOptions | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);

            // Show the folder browser dialog
            if (pFileDialog->Show(hWnd) == S_OK) {
                IShellItem* pItem;
                if (pFileDialog->GetResult(&pItem) == S_OK) {
                    PWSTR pszFolderPath;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFolderPath)) && pszFolderPath) {
                        // Convert to std::wstring and store in folderPath variable
                        folderPath = pszFolderPath;
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszFolderPath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }

            pFileDialog->Release();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }

    return folderPath;
}

inline StateInfo* GetAppState(HWND hwnd) {
    LONG_PTR ptr = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    StateInfo* pState = reinterpret_cast<StateInfo*>(ptr);
    return pState;
}

void DebugStateDisplay(HWND hWnd) {
    StateInfo* pState = GetAppState(hWnd);
    OutputDebugString(L"\n******************\n");

    OutputDebugString(L"Input: ");
    OutputDebugString(pState->inputFolder.c_str());
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");

    OutputDebugString(L"Output: ");
    OutputDebugString(pState->outputFolder.c_str());
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");

    OutputDebugString(L"N: ");
    OutputDebugString(pState->N.c_str());
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");

    OutputDebugString(L"Found: ");
    OutputDebugString(pState->found.c_str());
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");

    OutputDebugString(L"Selected: ");
    OutputDebugString(pState->selected.c_str());
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");

    OutputDebugString(L"******************\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: This `StateInfo* pState = reinterpret_cast<StateInfo*>(lParam);` Never use LPARAM to pass pointers. Also code with reinterpret_cast is usually suspicious anyway.

Comment: @PepijnKramer; so it seems that in my ignorance I used totally wrong design. Can you recommend how to approach this? End goal is the same: i want to read from dialog, and set this value to application state. if this cannot be done directly, the indirectly is fine, if possible without any additional global variable.

Comment: As it says [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxparama), The `lParam` you pass to `DialogBoxParam` is "The value to pass to the dialog box in the `lParam` parameter of the `WM_INITDIALOG` message." But you are using it in the `WM_COMMAND` message. The `lParam` of the `WM_COMMAND` message [contains something else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command).

Comment: @PepijnKramer _Never use LPARAM to pass pointers_ - I see you don't program on Windows.  The WIN32 API does this extensively.

Comment: @PaulSanders It has been a long time ago. But I remember issues when moving between 16/32 bits OS and pointers suddenly didn't fit anymore. Did something change?

Comment: @PepijnKramer No, `LPARAM` was always 32 bits, even in 16 bit Windows.  As were (far) pointers.  But `WPARAM` wasn't, and that caused a few fun and games when an `HWND` grew from 16 bits to 32 bits.  I was pleased to leave all that nonsense behind, I can tell you.  And, ofc, both are now 64 bits, so the transition from 32 bit Windows to 64 bit Windows was relatively painless.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks for that feedback, yes I was pleased to leave all that behind too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on helpful comment by
[@Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) that what is passed to different commands is completely different and also based on [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53642885/4154250) I have been able to find the solution. 
I am copying `pState->N` value to `gBuffer` (in order to have the current number already prefilled in dialog), then sending the address of the `gBuffer` as LPARAM to `NumberInputDialogProc` function. There `gBuffer` is filled with value from dialog and I write it to back to state property`pState->N`.
Relevant changes in `WndProc`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    wchar_t gBuffer[MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE + 1] = { 0 }
    /** other code ... */
    case ID_SETUP_NUMBEROFFILES:
            wcscpy_s(gBuffer, MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE + 1, pState->N.c_str());
            callback_result = DialogBoxParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG3), hWnd, NumberInputDialogProc, (LPARAM)(&gBuffer));
            if (callback_result ==IDOK) {
                pState->N = gBuffer;
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            DebugStateDisplay(pState);
            break;
    /** other code ... */
}
```

And in `NumberInputDialogProc` function, I store this address to DWLP_USER in WM_INITDIALOG and retrieve it back in WM_COMMAND where it is used to store number as text:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK NumberInputDialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    int number;
    wchar_t* gBuffer;

    switch (message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_NUMBER_EDIT, (wchar_t*)lParam);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, DWLP_USER, lParam);
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDOK:
            gBuffer = (wchar_t*)GetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, DWLP_USER);
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_NUMBER_EDIT, gBuffer, MAX_INPUT_NUMBER_SIZE+1);
            number = _ttoi(gBuffer);
            if (number >= 1 && number <= 999) {
                EndDialog(hDlg, IDOK);
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
            else {
                SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_ERROR_MSG, _T("Enter a number between 1 and 999"));
            }
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, IDCANCEL);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

I apologize in advance if I used unidiomatic C++ terminology anywhere. I will edit the post if required to fix that.